# Angular form for async edit

Tags: angular

I have created a profile page where user can directly manipulate and update the values they want to change.
This function is created by using an editState toggle and then storing the editValue as a temp storage for comparison before triggering the right field to go between displaying its text of form input.

This works really well... until i try to change the current input value whereby the editValue will then no longer be equal to the value that i'm currently editing.

Is there an easier solution that I'm overlooking to prevent this from triggering my input back to display?

here is the html

```html
<div class="inner-adjust">
    <div class="pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">User Profile</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- Show user data when logged in -->
    <div *ngIf="(user$ | async) as user">
        <div class="row" *ngIf="(userPrivate$ | async) as userPrivate">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="media">
                    <img class="align-self-start mr-5 img-thumbnail rounded-circle"
                        src="{{(user.profile_pic) ? user.profile_pic : '/assets/img/placeholder-user.jpg'}}"
                        alt="{{user.username}}">
                    <div class="media-body col-9 text-left">
                        <p>Hello: <strong>{{(user.username)}}</strong></p>
                        <p>User since: <strong>{{getDate(user.created_time)}}</strong></p>
                        <p>Email: <strong>{{userPrivate.email}}</strong></p>
                        <p>Date of Birth: <strong>{{getDate(userPrivate.date_of_birth)}}</strong></p>
                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="col-4">Gender: &nbsp;</p>
                            <div *ngIf="!editState || editValue !=  userPrivate.gender" class="col-8">
                                <p>{{userPrivate.gender}}
                                    <i (click)="editUser($event,  userPrivate.gender)" class="fa fa-pencil mt-2"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="editState && editValue == userPrivate.gender" class="col-8">
                                <form (ngSubmit)="updateUser(userPrivate.gender)" class="row">
                                    <input class="form-edit col-9" type="text" [(ngModel)]="userPrivate.gender"
                                        name="occupation">
                                    <i (click)="updateUser( user, userPrivate, userPrivate.date_of_birth)"
                                        class="fa fa-save mt-2 col-3"></i>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <p class="col-4">Occupation: &nbsp;</p>
                            <div *ngIf="!editState || editValue != user.occupation" class="col-8">
                                <p>{{user.occupation}}
                                    <i (click)="editUser($event, user.occupation)" class="fa fa-pencil mt-2"></i>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div *ngIf="editState && editValue == user.occupation" class="col-8">
                                <form (ngSubmit)="updateUser(user.occupation)" class="row">
                                    <input class="form-edit col-9" type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.occupation"
                                        name="occupation">
                                    <i (click)="updateUser( user, userPrivate, userPrivate.date_of_birth)"
                                        class="fa fa-save mt-2 col-3"></i>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and in my ts

```js
  editUser(event, value) {
    this.editState = true;
    this.editValue = value;
  }
  updateUser(user, privateUser, dob){
    this.editState = false;
    this.editValue = null;
    console.log(dob);
    this.userService.updateUser(user, privateUser, dob);
  }
```

these are the functions that would be responsible for the toggling and updating

Comment: Can you explain `*ngIf="!editState || editValue !=  userPrivate.gender"` in a sentence?

Comment: if the editstate is false or if the edit value isn't equal to the gender value then I will display the <p> text. I'm using or here since the edit state might be true but for another field so using `*ngIf="!editState && editValue != userPrivate.gender"` would mean if i'm editting occupation, the gender display text will not show